# Prove the series converges to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Consider the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+k^2}$
>
> Show that this series converges to a continuous function that is
>   defined for all $x ∈ R$.

I'm unsure how to approach this. I'm wondering if I can use the M-test to show that this series converges. Since the power series is continuous, it would have to converge to a continuous function, $f$, if it does converge. Is this correct?

Comment: $ \frac{1}{x^2+k^2} \le \frac{1}{k^2}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on this? I'm unsure what to do with this?

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x^2+k^2}~=~\dfrac\pi x~\coth(\pi x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about using the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test):

- $\dfrac{1}{x^2+k^2}$ is uniformly bounded on $x$ because $ \dfrac{1}{x^2+k^2} \le \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ .
- $\displaystyle \sum_k \dfrac{1}{k^2} < \infty$ (you may even know that the value is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$).
- Apply the Weierstrass M-test to conclude that the original series converges uniformly.
- Use that if a series of continuous functions converges uniformly, then the limit is a continuous function.